# Adding props variable inside JSX if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Inside my render function I want to add an if eles shorthand statement with a prop value.

```
<div>
   { flag ? 'overcharge' :
    <sup>$</sup>{total}
   }
</div>
```

My linter is not allowing me. `{amount}` says `Unexpected token should be '}'`
Anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: I think you are missing an ending }

Comment: Oops, yea even with that I get the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a closing `}` and you have unwrapped JSX `<sup>$</sup>{total}`.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

<div>
   { flag 
       ? 'overcharge'
       : <Fragment>
          <sup>$</sup>{total} 
         </Fragment>
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Ah never though of that works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing two things here: closing braces and Parent div which is required while returning react elements.

Use `React.Fragment` from react v16. It allows you render multiple components at the same level without appending extra div to your DOM.

```
 {flag ? 'overcharge' : <React.Fragment><sup>$</sup> {total}</React.Fragment> }
```